# Extra p tags in profile form inserted via WP shortcode

Tags: wordpress

Even though I have disabled autop for shortcodes, I end up with a lot of 
extra `<p>` tags in the generated form. Here's a snippet:

```
<div id="editrow-email-Primary" class="crm-section editrow_email-Primary-section form-item">
  <div class="label">
    <label for="email-Primary"> Email
      <span lass="crm-marker" title="This field is required.">*</span>
</p><p>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="edit-value content">
    <input maxlength="254" size="30" name="email-Primary" type="text" id="email-Primary" class="big crm-form-text required" />
  </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Note the stray `</p><p>` in the middle. But while a bit wrong, this is ok. What's really a problem is that the generated JS code for the datepicker *also* gets a bunch of random `<p>` tags:

`<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/</p><p>CRM.$(function($){</p><p>var $dateElement=$('input[name=birth_date_display_57599e0ccbe99].dateplugin:not(.hasDatepicker)');</p><p>`

This completely breaks the JS.

Any hints on how to figure out where these tags are coming from would be helpful. This sure looks like autop acting up, but I don't see how it could affect the shortcode's generated *content*, even when it might wrap the shortcode itself.

Comment: What CiviCRM version? Also have you tried switching to the default Wordpress theme?

Comment: @Andrei - thanks for the response. I'm sure it was specific to my theme (see my answer below).

Comment: @autarch glad you figured it out. Voted up. What theme are you using, just to be aware in the future.

Comment: @Andre - it's a customized theme based off The Bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. Here's the auto-relevant bits from `functions.php`:

```
function better_wpautop($pee){
    return wpautop( $pee, $br=0 );
}

/* This is a hack to make sure that wordpress's autop filter doesn't apply to shortcodes */
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'better_wpautop', 11 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 12 );
```

I thought `shortcode_unautop` was supposed to fix this, but I took a look at it and it's a huge hack that tries to strip p tags back out of shortcode content in a truly terrifying way with a regex ([ob Zalgo reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). So I made a copy of my standard page template and added the following to the top:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'better_wpautop', 11 );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 12 );
```

Now there is nothing autop related happening, which is fine, since the entire content of the page comes from the CiviCRM profile.

Comment: Just want to check- was the issue in your local site?   I just checked a few of ours and I am not getting any random <p> tags

Comment: @KevinCristiano - I wouldn't be surprised if it was specific to how autop was configured on my site. That said, the config I used (with the altered filter stack) is recommended in various places where people have discussed issues with the WP autop feature, so I wouldn't be surprised if someone else encountered it.

Comment: @KevinCristiano - argh, hit enter too soon. I think it'd be nice if CiviCRM could disable autop for the content that it generates somehow. I don't know if that's possible.